# macOS launchpad icons became blurry

Tags: macos, display, icon, resolution, launchpad

macOS launchpad icons became blurry as compared to those in the dock. See System Preferences for example. Resolution has become really low. I don't why. What could be the reason for the same?

[image: Example image]
[image: Example on external 1080p monitor]

Comment: They don't look any different to the icons in the Dock. What's your screen resolution set to?

Comment: 1280x800. It's different compare settings icon

Comment: 1280x800 is very low rez anyway. The icons aren't the same size, but it looks like one is being antialiased & the other isn't. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkJFY.png Try at your screen's native resolution rather than scaled & see how they compare.

Comment: it is my native resolution, I have macbook pro 2012 13 (non-retina).

Answer (score 1):

It fixed by itself -_-[image: Img]

I dunno how and why...
UPDATE: The problem is in mozilla firefox, while it opened in any desktop it creates this bug somehow :/ ?!